# Codeigniter auto-update search with %LIKE%

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I am new to codeigniter. I have done auto suggest search using simple mysql but not with codeigniter's active records. It's very confusing to me.

My mysql format was :

```
$s = $_POST['s'];
$search_result = explode(' ', $s);

$query_temp = '';
$i=0;
foreach($search_result as $search){
$i++;
if($i == 1){
$query_temp .= "title LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%' OR keywords LIKE '%$search%' OR link LIKE '%$search%'";
}else{
$query_temp .= "OR title LIKE '%$search%' OR description LIKE '%$search%' OR keywords LIKE '%$search%' OR link LIKE '%$search%'";
}
}

$search_query = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['s']));
$run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE $query_temp")or die(mysql_error());
```

But here I have to search from 3 tables. I have no idea how to do it in this format in codeigniter..

Comment: three table or three column of same table

Comment: three columns of three separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

If field 'title' belongs to table 'a', 
field 'description' belongs to table 'b' 
and field 'keywords' belongs to table 'c' then you can use like this :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('a, b, c');
$this->db->like(a.title, $search);
$this->db->or_like(b.description, $search);
$this->db->or_like(c.keywords, $search);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I have to put these `like` and `or_like` within `foreach` loop. right? and `select`, `from` and `$query` outside the loop?